# sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected - scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I just cloned a repo and installed scala version `2.11.8` and did `brew install sbt`. The versions specified in the repo are - scala version `2.11.8` and sbt version `0.13.13`. The only difference is I have sbt version `0.13.15`. Still - when I execute sbt in the root of the repo, I get the error :

```
sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.incompatiblePlugins(PluginDiscovery.scala:145)
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.loadModules(PluginDiscovery.scala:135)
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.binarySourceModules(PluginDiscovery.scala:124)
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.discover$1(PluginDiscovery.scala:28)
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.discoverAll(PluginDiscovery.scala:38)
    at sbt.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:900)
    at sbt.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:857)
    at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:852)
    at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:840)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1$$anonfun$34.apply(Load.scala:465)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1$$anonfun$34.apply(Load.scala:465)
    at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.apply(Load.scala:464)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.apply(Load.scala:459)
    at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:459)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Load.scala:311)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Load.scala:310)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:365)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:320)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:316)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:305)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$4.apply(Load.scala:146)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$4.apply(Load.scala:146)
    at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:146)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:39)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:496)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:496)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:488)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:488)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/typesafe/sbt/SbtNativePackager$ : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:295)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:14)
    at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getCheckedObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:20)
    at sbt.ModuleUtilities$$anonfun$getCheckedObjects$1.apply(ModuleUtilities.scala:23)
    at sbt.ModuleUtilities$$anonfun$getCheckedObjects$1.apply(ModuleUtilities.scala:23)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.map(Stream.scala:376)
    at sbt.ModuleUtilities$.getCheckedObjects(ModuleUtilities.scala:23)
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.loadModules(PluginDiscovery.scala:130)
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.binarySourceModules(PluginDiscovery.scala:124)
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.discover$1(PluginDiscovery.scala:28)
    at sbt.PluginDiscovery$.discoverAll(PluginDiscovery.scala:38)
    at sbt.Load$.loadPlugins(Load.scala:900)
    at sbt.Load$.loadPluginDefinition(Load.scala:857)
    at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:852)
    at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:840)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1$$anonfun$34.apply(Load.scala:465)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1$$anonfun$34.apply(Load.scala:465)
    at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.apply(Load.scala:464)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.apply(Load.scala:459)
    at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
    at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:459)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Load.scala:311)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Load.scala:310)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
    at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
    at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
    at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:365)
    at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:320)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:316)
    at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:305)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$4.apply(Load.scala:146)
    at sbt.Load$$anonfun$4.apply(Load.scala:146)
    at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
    at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:146)
    at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:39)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:496)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:496)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:488)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:488)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Can anyone help what steps should I take to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/typesafe/sbt/SbtNativePackager$ : Unsupported major.minor version
>   51.0

Check java version. Your installed version is lower than sbt-native-packager requires.

Comment: Thanks for the help!